# How to filter files like AND operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a file list where every file contains basic info like `name`, `size` and `last-modified` fields.

I have `--filter` option to match against the files and incase of multiple filters, it should be like `AND` operation.

- `file_list`

```
file_list = {
        "items": [
            {
                "last-modified": "2021-06-14T10:20:14",
                "name": "helloworld-slurm-kub.cwl",
                "size": {"human_readable": "965 Bytes", "raw": 965},
            },
            {
                "last-modified": "2021-06-14T10:20:14",
                "name": "helloworld-htcondor.yml",
                "size": {"human_readable": "122 Bytes", "raw": 122},
            },
            {
                "last-modified": "2021-06-14T10:20:14",
                "name": "helloworld-kub.cwl",
                "size": {"human_readable": "867 Bytes", "raw": 867},
            },
        ]
    }
```

- `search_filters`

```
search_filter = {
 "name": ["slurm", "kub"],
 "last-modified": ["21"],
}

# This is like sub-string matching and condition would be:

name contains "slurm" AND "kub" AND last-modified contains "21"
```

I want expected result to be one of the names **and** last-modified to contain `21` which would look like:

```
file_list = {
        "items": [
            {
                "last-modified": "2021-06-14T10:20:14",
                "name": "helloworld-slurm-kub.cwl",
                "size": {"human_readable": "965 Bytes", "raw": 965},
            },
        ]
    }
```

I have written a function to process every file and I am not getting the expected results.

```
def file_filter(file_list_info, search_filter):
 file_match = False
 for k, v in file_list_info:
   if k in search_filter:
     if not any(_filter in v for _filter in search_filter[k]):
       file_match = False
       break # if none of the values match in any filter, it will not be matching the condition.
     else:
       file_match = True
       continue
  return file_match # if True file will be included in the result.
```

What I am missing?

Comment: What results *are* you getting - be specific.

Comment: And please make your code a [mre] with imports and minimal data and missing functions included; anyone should be able to do a single copy/paste (you currently have four fragments to assemble, why should anyone bother doing this work?)into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the problem you’re seeing. The key thing for you is that providing a [mre] makes it much more likely you’ll get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension with `all()` to filter out elements that doesn't satisfy the search criteria:

```py
out = {
    "items": [
        d
        for d in file_list["items"]
        if all(vv in d[k] for k, v in search_filter.items() for vv in v)
    ]
}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "items": [
        {
            "last-modified": "2021-06-14T10:20:14",
            "name": "helloworld-slurm-kub.cwl",
            "size": {"human_readable": "965 Bytes", "raw": 965},
        }
    ]
}
```